Couple in a car crash in US desert
I think this was a TV move from the 1970s. A couple have an accident while driving somewhere in the US; maybe the Nevada desert or somewhere similar. They are taken to a nearby hotel to recuperate. They slowly begin to realise that the other guests have been at the hotel for a long time, and they suspect something strange is going on. They try to leave, but when they reach the perimeter of the hotel grounds, they see a huge sandstorm for as far as the eye can see.
They realise they can never leave the hotel and that they are, in fact, dead.

Sounds like Beneath the Dark, but this was made in 2010, not in the 70's.
IMDb:

While crossing the Mojave Desert to go to a wedding in Los Angeles,
  Paul and his girlfriend Adrienne have a car accident. They decide to
  spend for the night into the Roy's Motel and Cafe and they check-in
  with a man called Frank. Paul is uncomfortable to disclose a secret to
  Adrienne while Frank's wife Sandy has a hidden past that affects their
  lives. Along the night, weird and surreal things happen to Paul until
  a stranger help him to discover the truth and make a choice.

Except for the year, the movie matches your description. 
Trailer:



Full movie in Spanish:



